# Create keyboard shortcut to switch between html an typescript files with same name

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I want to create keyboard shortcut (ex <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) to switch between `mypage.html` and `mypage.ts` files. I have project in which I have one html and one typescript(ts) file with same names. Can I create hotkey to switch between them like we have hotkey <kbd>F7</kbd> for asp.net web forms designer and code behind file. I am working on angular 2 project and developing with visual studio 2013. Some of my team members also have vs15.

[image: html file and ts file with same names.]

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio 2019 you can use this extension [Angular Html TS Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OAS.593771d0-13b5-4de6-a192-165dd6f16144)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension (commercial) to group files with the same name and quickly switch between different extensions using the TabsStudio.OpenCorrespondingFile command.